# My spider is too slow for my needs and I have no idea how to fix it

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I'm a beginner in data scraping and I want to create a spider which retrieves all the jobs available from a local website, given a keyword and a city.

I also want to retrieve data from each job, so I have to follow that link.

I have two problems with my code that I have no idea how to fix (after half a day of trying myself) - the fact that each request takes 7 seconds, which is very slow (if I have 1-2k jobs to scrape... that would be way too much).

I've searched online how to fix it, and I fixed my selectors - now I think I use only the bare minimum, and also the faster ones. I've also started using explicit waits instead of implicit ones - and I got 7seconds per request now, but I don't know how to make it less.

Also, I want to crawl every link, but I also want to go on the next page if there is one. That's why I have two yields statements in my parse method, but my approach didn't work. I don't get the next pages and I'd like to.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

from scrapy.spiders.init import InitSpider
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest

class ExampleSpider(InitSpider):
    name = 'example'
    
    def init_request(self):
        yield SeleniumRequest(
            url='https://www.ejobs.ro/',
            wait_time=3,
            callback=self.search
        )

        return self.initialized()

    def search(self, response):
        driver = response.meta['driver']
        search_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='keyword']")
        search_input.send_keys("programator")

        search_input2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='s2id_autogen1']")
        search_input2.send_keys("bucuresti")
        selectieOras = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='s2id_autogen1_search']")
        selectieOras.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

        submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='submit']")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", submit)

        try:
            element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "searchSection"))
            )
        finally:
            yield SeleniumRequest(
                url=driver.current_url,
                wait_time=3,
                callback=self.parse
            )

    def parse(self, response):  
        driver = response.meta['driver'] 
        try:
            element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "searchSection"))
            )
        finally:
            html = driver.page_source
            response_obj = Selector(text=html)
            
            links = response_obj.xpath("//div[@class='jobitem-body']")
            for link in links:
                URL = link.xpath(".//a[contains(@class, 'title')]/@href").get()

                if URL:
                    yield SeleniumRequest(
                        url=URL,
                        wait_time=3,
                        callback=self.parse_res
                    )

            next = response_obj.xpath("//div[@id='searchPagination']/li[@class='next']/a/@href")
            if next:
                hrefLink = next.get()
                yield SeleniumRequest(
                    url=hrefLink,
                    wait_time=3,
                    callback=self.parse
                )

    def parse_res(self, response):
        yield {
            'title': response.xpath("//h1[@class='jobad-title']/text()").get()
        }
```

Is there any way to fix those 2 problems? I'm a complete beginner in web scraping and I've tried everything I could find in the docs and online, I have no other ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: The selectors shouldn't make much/any difference at all -- if you're doing everything right on your side, the bottleneck will be how quickly the server responds to your requests, and that's something you can't control. Ideally, you'd talk to the people who run the server and see about getting a bulk API that's efficient for them to provide and also much higher-throughput.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy can you look into it yourself, please? The website I'm trying to scrape is a very popular (and obviously quite big) website from my country for finding jobs, it isn't easy to talk to them. I don't know, I might be doing something wrong in my code. 7s/request is a lot of time - isn't there any way to lower it? Also, can you check my pagination problem? I think that it will be a great thing for me to learn how get results from all the pages while also follow each link to be honest, I'm sure that I will have to do this again in the future.

Comment: He's not going to do your job, for goodness sakes.  Our job is to give you hints to solve your problems, not to do all the work.

Comment: @TimRoberts I never asked that. My idea was to check if he gets the same time per request so I know if the problem is on my side or not.

Answer (score -1):

1. why u are using selenium request instead of scrapy request do you
   need to render java script ?
2. why you are using wait_time=3 ? do you really needs to wait for that long ?
3. check do you need to disable Auto Throttle ?
4. May be you need to increase concurrent requests in settings as well

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.